# How to display a second JSON element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to set up a newsletter which gets its contents from a JSON file with a number of articles consisting of a title and a text. Using JavaScript, I want the HTML page to display a list with all the titles. When a user clicks on one of the titles, the corresponding text should be displayed (and, ideally, when he or she clicks on another title, the former text should be hidden and only the new one should be visible - but it may all be in another iteration).

The script lists the titles, but so far I've only been able to make them into HTML links sending the user to a non-existing page where I had hoped instead to show the texts in a div by means of innerHTML. I'm rather new to JavaScript (and ignorant about jQuery) so I'd be glad if somebody could tell me how to get the text elements from the JSON file and display them, one at a time.

My JSON data:

```
var article = [
    {
        "title": "This is title no. 1",
        "text": "Here is the text of the first article"
    },
    {
        "title": "This is title no. 2",
        "text": "Here is the text of the second article"
    },
    {
        "title": "This is title no. 3",
        "text": "Here is the text of the third article"

    }
]
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="newsletter.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getData() {
            for(i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML += "<li>" + article[i].title.link(article[i].text) + "</li>";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getData()">
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that your question has **nothing** to do with JSON. What you posted is a normal *JavaScript array*. And even if you got the data as JSON somewhere, it would be irrelevant since you problem seems to be with processing the array. JSON is a language-independent, textual, data exchange format. What you have, `var article = [...];`, is JavaScript.

Comment: Ok it looks like a JSON question but you've shown the data as a javascript array. Is it instead supposed to get the data from `newsletter.json` and you've just given that array to show how it would work?

Comment: @Popnoodles: Since the OP mentions that he is able to display the titles, I believe `article` is indeed contained in the other script and contains an array.

Comment: Ah so you think his newsletter.json is not json. I can see that being true.

Comment: @Popnoodles: Especially since it's included as a script with `type="text/javascript"`. If it really contained JSON, it would still be evaluated as JavaScript and throw a syntax error. `article` would not exist and the other script would error as well.

Comment: I had assumed that include was part of the problem, and he/she had just expected the browser to know what to do with it, as people often do.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion so thanks for pointing it out. I've tried to migrate the newsletter from XML to JSON adapting a demonstration from a JavaScript and JSON Essentials book with an alternating use of .js and .json files as data source. And yes, newsletter.json contains the array, and I included it here simply not to leave out any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy to do with jQuery.

See here for a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/pk7264u6/

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
function getData() {
    var html = '';

    for(i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
        html += "<li data-text='" + "'>" + article[i].title.link(article[i].text) + "</li>";
    }
    $('#showData').html('<ul>' + html + '</ul>');

    // Use jQuery 'on' to run code when any Anchor tag inside the #showData div is clicked.
    $('#showData').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

        // remove any previously displayed text (in divs with the .text class)
        $('#showData .text').remove();    

        // after the current element (the anchor tag that was clicked) add a new div with the class .text.  Inside that div, display the href attribute of the anchor tag that was clicked.
        $(this).after('<div class="text">' + $(this).attr('href') + '</div>');

        // disable normal anchor handling so you don't get taken to a non-existent page.
        e.preventDefault();    

    });

}

// Use jQuery $(document).ready to make sure the DOM is loaded before you run anything (http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) instead of the onLoad in body.
$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had hoped for a JavaScript solution, but I suppose that, although it would have looked more familiar to me, it would also be more complex. At any rate, this seems to make out a strong case for jQuery so I'll try to proceed with that.